# Travis CI -- Docker run shell to extra Values

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am currently using Travis-CI, I am trying to do something like the following but I get just an empty value for the variable.

`ANSIBLE_VERSION=$(docker run -d <ID/TAG> /bin/bash -c "ansible --version"|head -1 |awk '{print $2}')`

I have tested the command on my local machine and it works correctly, so I am not sure what the problem might be Travis related?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is due to the following:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3149